# Append binary data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

given the following MongoDB document:

```
{
    "d" : [
        {
            "h" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "h" : [
                BinData(0,"..."),
                BinData(0,"...")
            ]
        }]
}
```

I want to transform this data that the "d" property contains only 1 BinData that holds the concatenation of the current model.

```
{
    "d" : BinData(0,"<concatenation of the above>")
}
```

Can somebody help me, how to do that?

btw: I would like to avoid client side JS code due to performance consideration -- if possible

Comment: didnt find a way to extract the value https://mongoplayground.net/p/y1DobZPxYFX  maybe if u use $function?